# Vertical center label with text area and with select and with textbox

Tags: css, forms

I have horizontally side by side: labels and text areas; labels and select.  I would like to have it such that:

1. The select input is vertically centered with the label for that select.  Say for example the select label takes up 5 lines then the select should be lined up so it appears to be on the same vertical level as teh 3rd line in the label side by side.  If the label text is one line high then the label and the select are vertically on the same level.  If the label text is 2 lines high then the select should appear to be on a level between the two lines.
2. For text areas the label text is vertically centred with the text area and the text area is vertically centered with the label.  Say the text area is 5 lines high and the label is one line hight then the label should appear to be level with the 3rd line in the text area.  Say the text area is 2 lines high and the label is 4 lines high then the text area should line level with the middle 2 lines in the label.
3. For text box similar to item 1, with the text box lining up with middle line in the label.

HTML

```
    <div class="fieldSet"><fieldset>
     <p>
      <label class="field" for="name">Name:</label>
      <input id="name" type="text" name="name" class="textbox" >
     </p>       
     <p>
      <label class="field" for="life">Life Number:</label>
      <input id="life" type="text" name="life" class="textbox" style="width:85px;">
      <label class="field" for="annual">Annual Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Number:</label>
      <input id="annual" type="text" name="annual" class="textbox" style="width:85px;">
      <label class="field" for="maleFemale" style="width:125px;">M/F:</label>
      <input id="maleFemale" type="text" name="maleFemale" class="textbox" style="width:40px;">
     </p>
     <p>
      <label class="field" for="runYesNo">Running, Yes/No?:</label>
      <select name="runYesNo" id="runYesNo">
       <option value="?" selected>Yes/No?</option>
       <option value= "Yes">Yes</option>
       <option value= "No">No</option>
      </select>
     </p>
     <p>
      <label class="field" for="predMins">Predicted 5km blah blah blah blah blah blah:</label>
      <input id="predMins" type="text" name="predMins" class="textbox" style="width:85px;">
      <label class="field" for="predSecs">Seconds:</label>
      <input id="predSecs" type="text" name="predSecs" class="textbox" style="width:85px;">
     </p>
     <p>
      <label class="field" for="helpOut">Blah Blah Blah Blah are you Available to Assist / Help Out / Officiate / Steward on the Night?, Yes/No:</label>
      <select name="helpOut" id="helpOut">
       <option value="?" selected>Yes/No</option>
       <option value= "Yes">Yes</option>
       <option value= "No">No</option>
      </select>
     </p>
     <p>
      <label class="field" for="comments">Comments:</label>
      <textarea id="comments" name="comments"  ROWS=10 WRAP="SOFT" >Comments go here.......</textarea>
     </p>
    </fieldset></div>
```

CSS

```
form{
 display: block;
 width:800px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 text-align: center;
 padding:0;
}

div.fieldSet {
 width:798px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}

fieldset{
 border: none;
 margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
 padding: 0px 0px 15px 0px;
}

legend{
 width: 100%;
 padding: 0px;
 text-align: center;
}
label.field{
 text-align: right;
 width: 190px;
 float:left;
 vertical-align: middle;
}

input.textbox{
 width: 560px;
 float: left;
 height: 25px;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
fieldset p{
 clear: both;
 vertical-align: middle;
 text-align : left;
}
textarea {
 width:560px;
}
select {
 width:270px;
 display:block;
 float: left;
}
```

I would appreciate advise on how to achieve the layout that I am looking for.

Thank you for reading this.

[image: This picture "BEFORE" is what I get with the above CSS]

[image: This is what I want to achieve, "AFTER" changes to the CSS]

Comment: I think it's not possible via css. You need to use javascript to achieve such behaviour.

Comment: can you add a image of what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Try this >>>>>>>[Better-vertical-Alignment](http://jsfiddle.net/S3xYS/)

**css**

---

```
label.field{
 text-align: right;
 width: 190px;
 float:left;
 vertical-align: middle;
 line-height:25px;
}
```

so for the vertical alignment play with **line-height:25px** with **vertical-align:middle**!