# Is it possible to vertically center multi-line labels?

Tags: html, css, forms

Since I've been researching and working on it for hours with no luck, I assume the answer is no, but would love confirmation one way or another.

I have a multi-line label to the left of a select field.  Assume the label is 3 wrapped lines.  I would like the middle line of the label to match up vertically with the select field.  Like this:

```
Label Line 1
Label Line 2        SelectField
Label Line 3
```

Basically, my question is very similar to this one from a couple of years ago, which was not answered definitively:  [Vertical center label with text area and with select and with textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24984439/vertical-center-label-with-text-area-and-with-select-and-with-textbox).  Someone responded that javascript is required.

I have a [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/gpd209/qnn3r85n/2/) with my efforts so far.  I've found some interesting variations, but nothing matches what I'm looking for.

Can someone confirm whether this is or is not possible?  Thanks!!!

[EDIT: Spelling]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

HTML

```
<div class= 'divclass'>
    <label class="labelleft" for='name'>NAME 1 Very Long Multi-Line Label:</label>
    <select class='selectclass'>
        <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
        <option value="No">No</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class= 'divclass'>
    <label class="labelleft" for='name'>NAME 1 Very Long Multi-Line Label:</label>
    <select class='selectclass'>
        <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
        <option value="No">No</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class= 'divclass'>
    <label class="labelleft" for='name'>NAME 1 Very Long Multi-Line Label:</label>
    <select class='selectclass'>
        <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
        <option value="No">No</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div.divclass {
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 150px;
    width: 400px;
}
label.labelleft {
    width: 90px;
    text-align: right;
    background: lightblue;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: none;
}
select.selectclass {
    width: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rw1u5vsc/)

Comment: That's beautiful!  I should have posted this many hours ago :)

Answer (score 0):

Just use a table.

```css
td { vertical-align: middle; }
.narrow { width:8em; padding-right: 2em; }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="narrow"><label for="menu">Label text wrapped across multiple lines</label></td>
    <td><select name="menu" id="menu">
      <option>Menu item #1</option>
      <option>Menu item #2</option>
      <option>Menu item #3</option>
      <option>Menu item #4</option>
    </select></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, use `flexbox`.Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/qnn3r85n/3/) out. Key is to Use following code in your fiddle.

```
div.divclass {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: start;
  height: 150px;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

select.selectclass {
  width: 100px;
  display: flex;
}
```

Read more about `flexbox` [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: this also looks perfect.  Thanks!  I wish I could pick two responses as working solutions.  And I'll read more about flexbox - looks quite useful.

Comment: IMO this is a better solution. it applied everywhere + it will make things perfectly center, without any hard coded values